# MonoTouch generic limitations and the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

The MonoTouch [documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Generic_Virtual_Methods) states that it doesn't support virtual generic methods.

However, in my MonoTouch project I have the classes

```
public class ListMaker<T>
{
    public ListMaker() {}

    public virtual List<T> MakeList(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return new List<T>{t1, t2};
    }
}

public class ReverseListMaker<T> : ListMaker<T>
{
    public ReverseListMaker() {}

    public override List<T> MakeList(T t1, T t2)
    {
        return new List<T>{t2, t1};
    }
}
```

and elsewhere...

```
ListMaker<string> lm = new ReverseListMaker<string>();
List<string> strings = lm.MakeList("hello", "world");
```

Now, my expectation is that this shouldn't compile. However, it is compiling and running on the iOS simulator.

Does the limitation apply only to the actual ARM architecture of the devices? Or is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answers:**

> Does the limitation apply only to the actual ARM architecture of the devices?

Yes

> Or is the documentation outdated?

No

**Long answer:**

Most of the MonoTouch [limitations](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations) are dictated by the rules that **all** applications must follow to run on iOS **devices**.

That includes some limitations on generic because the **AOT** (ahead-of-time) compiler cannot know every possible cases for which code needs to be generated.

However since the rules applies only to **device** and that AOT compilation takes quite some time, MonoTouch will use the **JIT** (just-in-time) compiler when used on the simulator. This allows faster **code-build-debug** cycles and makes development **much** more enjoyable. The downside is that this can hides a few limitations (like the AOT ones).

Nevertheless there are many situations where the iOS simulator behaves very differently than the devices. IOW something that works on the simulator does not mean it will work (at least as nicely or at all) on devices. As such all (or most) testing should be done on (if possible many different) devices.

Comment: It's a method on a generic type but it's not a generic method... Are you sure that it doesn't work on MonoTouch ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a generic method, it's a method on a generic type. It's fine on the simulator and device. If you had another generic type parameter in that method (and kept the method virtual), then it wouldn't work on the simulator or device.